# How can you get information from a form and append it to a table?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a website in which I need to get information from a form and store it in a table that everyone else can see.

For example, every time someone fills out the form and presses "submit", the user is taken to another page where a table is created. The table will append the information that the user just put. If the tab is refreshed or someone else visits the site, the information in the table will still be there.

I believe I need a server for this, so if there is any guidance regarding how to use a server, it would be much appreciated. -THERE ARE COMMENTS REGARDING THIS, NOW I NEED AN ANSWER TO THE QUESTION BELOW

However, more specifically, I want to at least be able to use local storage to find out the technique for saving the data and keeping it in the table for at least one user.

I have some code below that is attempting to use local storage, but it is not currently working. I have a form elsewhere, and I also call the div myresult in another page. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function refresh() {
    const result = document.getElementById("myresult");
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (saved) {
        const t =
        `<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${saved.name}</td>
                <td>${saved.lastname}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>`;

        myresult.innerHTML = t;
    }

    const form = document.getElementById("myform");
    form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        const {
            elements
        } = form;
        const output = {
            name: elements.name.value, 
            lastname: elements.lastname.value,
        };
        localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(output));
        const template =
            `<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${output.name}</td>
                <td>${output.lastname}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>`;
        myresult.innerHTML = template;
    })
}
```

Comment: There's a lot about how to setup servers online, like [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) intro to `express nodejs`. It uses the same syntax as your frontend JavaScript, howver it also implies that you have a local dev enviroment setup. Depending on if you are on windows, mac, or other, you will have to research how to get access to terminal, etc.

Comment: I'm new to all of this, but to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, I can download/make a server on my laptop and then when my website is published others will be able to get the information that is put on to the server from my computer?

Comment: No, you would create a local server on your computer for testing and development. You will need a remote server on the internet to share your work with the rest of the world.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Kinglish you can certainly have a server hosted locally if you have some machine that is always on and connected to the internet. It's just a bit more of a hassle. I definitely would use remote hosting for all projects that OP would be doing.

Comment: @charlie-map - true, thanks I should have mentioned it.... given the OPs experience level, I wanted to steer them away from opening their computer to the world and spend their learning on something more scalable.

Comment: @Kinglish yeah I agree - Since you need an entire system that is stably running constantly, it's not worth the time at this point. As for local dev environment (assuming OP is using Windows or Mac), I would point you towards [this Windows article](https://char.gd/blog/2017/how-to-set-up-the-perfect-modern-dev-environment-on-windows) and [this package manager for Mac](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). Of note: I have never done the Mac installation (on my own computer), but I've helped a lot of people get `homebrew` installed, and it seems to work well for what you likely want.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but do either of you know how I can do it for just myself using local storage? The code I provided in my original question aims to do that, but it isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is your use of your `form` element. Say your form had the following style:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input placeholder="Name">
  <input placeholder="LastName">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When you select using the JavaScript selector, you first do:

```
const {
    elements
} = form;
```

Try `console.log()`ing what elements is, and you may notice that elements might look a little different than what your code is presuming. When you `console.log()` (this shows up in the *browser* consoler, which you can find using **right click**, **inspect element**, **find the tab named `console`**), the response will look something like:

```
{
    0: <input placeholder="Name">,
    1: <input placeholder="LastName">,
    2: <input type="submit">
}
```

There will likely be some other JavaScript jargon in there, but this is the meat. When you do:

```
const output = {
    name: elements.name.value, 
    lastname: elements.lastname.value,
};
```

There is no value inside of the `elements` object called `name` or `lastname`. It is instead `0` and `1`. So the way we would change our output would be:

```
const output = {
    name: elements[0].value, 
    lastname: elements[1].value,
};
```

This is **not** the same as accessing an array, because we are accessing `elements` at the *key*s of `0` and `1`. The final step would be adding this into your code. I took the liberty of removing the semi-duplicated code (where you create the HTML and add it to the page), because all you have to do is call `refresh()` from within the form submit listener and then when it checks again, you would then see conceptually how local storage works. **Note**: if you call refresh from within the HTML listener, the listener should not be inside of the `refresh` function because it will just slap on a second listener, which means the next time you try submitting it will be trying to submit multiple times!

Here's what the code would look like with these updates. Be warned, the code will not work in a StackOverflow code snippet, since there is not access to local storage. If you want to test it briefly, I would suggest using [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/), which lets you easily run HTML, CSS, and JS as well as allows you to have access to local storage.

```js
function refresh() {
    const result = document.getElementById("myresult");
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (saved) {
        const t =
        `<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${saved.name}</td>
                <td>${saved.lastname}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>`;

        myresult.innerHTML = t;
    }
}

const form = document.getElementById("myform");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const {
        elements
    } = form;

    console.log(elements);
    const output = {
        name: elements[0].value, 
        lastname: elements[1].value,
    };

    console.log(output);
    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(output));

    refresh();
})
```

```css
/* CSS to help with displaying the table*/
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input placeholder="Name">
  <input placeholder="LastName">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="myresult">I added the div element here, but myresult may be a different tag than this</div>
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but in order to use the jQuery ($), all I have done is put it in <script>. Do I need to do something else? Also, this is all in my JS file. Do I need to move part of it to my HTML? When I inspect the console, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at refresh (JAVASCRIPT_ENTIREAPP.js:61)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (HTML_SECONDPAGE.html:9)"

Comment: You do not use jQuery in your code anywhere. Are you talking about when you select the `form` element and use `.addEventListener`? Make sure that you remove the use of `form.addEventListener(...)` from inside of the function `refresh`. The only connection is that you call `refresh()` from inside the submit event for your form.

Comment: What I meant is that the second part of the code that is not in the function, where is that? In my code, the "submit" button is clicked for the form. This takes the user to another page, where a table is created. This is where the refresh button is, and when they click "refresh", the table should appear. However, I don't necessarily need the "refresh" button, if the refresh function happens as soon as "submit" is created, that is better, in fact.

Comment: I moved the `form.addEventListener(...)` to after the function `refresh` because if you call `refresh()` from inside of the `form.addEventListener(..., e => {});` callback, then we just have to move that event listener to *after* our refresh function (or before really, just not inside) so that another event listener isn't attached to our `form` element (the way your original code was setup, if we ran `refresh()` twice, then when we submit to the `form` element, that code would run twice)

Comment: But when I call the refresh function, how does that part get called?

Comment: The only place you need to call `refresh()` is at the bottom of your event listener for `form` submission. We don't need that function to run *unless* the form has been submitted at least once. This could definitely be update to then take in data from a server, but this is a good start.